# DCG: Assigning remainder to a variable within DCG {} code

Tags: prolog, gnu, dcg

This answer: [Very basic dcg prolog syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902867/very-basic-dcg-prolog-syntax)  helped me a little but [X] only gets the next character, I want the whole enchilada, read on!

I am using GNU Prolog to write a command option parser and I am stuck on a DCG point. I have this grammar rule which looks for "foo --as=json" for example, and I just cannot work out how to get my hands on the result of "anything", the code:

```
as_opt --> "--as=", anything, { c( as_opt )}, !.
anything --> [], {c(anything_match)}.
```

And the gprolog expansion of that is:

```
as_opt([45, 45, 97, 115, 61|A], B) :-
        anything(A, C),
        c(as_opt), !,
        C = B.

anything(A, B) :-
        c(anything_match), !,
        A = B.
```

The "c()" predicate is simple and is just used to track that the rule executed with a format() to stdout so I could see what's going on as it runs. If I had written the code by hand I would do:

```
%% for completeness here!
c(Msg) :- format("Processed ~w~n", [Msg]).

as_opt([45, 45, 97, 115, 61|A], B) :-
        anything(A, C),
        c(as_opt), !,
        C = B,
        { g_assign( gvValue, B )}. %% just for example
```

Going back to the original DCG:

```
as_opt --> "--as=", anything, { c( as_opt ), gassign( gvValue, ??? )}, !.
```

So what goes where the "???" is. Is it possible...it must be. I am going to re-read the gprolog rules on how it expands DCG rules again in case I am about to (facepalm) myself but in the meantime any assistance would be most welcome.

Thanks,
Sean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for one of the simplest DCG non-terminals, which describes any list:

```
list --> [].
list --> [_], list.
```

To actually access the list that is being described, you introduce an argument:

```
list([])    --> [].
list([L|Ls) --> [L], list(Ls)
```

You can use it like this:

```
as_opt(Option) --> "--as=", list(Option).
```

Comment: mat, good answer. I guess being a noob with Prolog and DCG rules I have yet to appreciate the nuances! I will work with that and no doubt tracing it will help me grok it more. Thanks. A good concise answer.

Comment: Bummer. Should have tried the code, got too excited! It doesn't work for me just yet. It outputs "[]" as the value of option. I will try harder...back soon I guess...

Comment: mat, I think the order of the rules is wrong. If I put the empty list case last things look a lot better! Is that an oversight on your part do you think?

Comment: OK. I have now accepted this answer because it works for me once I swapped the rules around. I can work with this and also understand Prolog a little more. Thanks mat.

Comment: If the string `Ls` you want to parse consists of "--as=<nonempty>", then `?- phrase(as_opt(O), Ls)` cannot succeed with `O=[]`. Always use the `phrase/2` interface to DCGs. There are cases where swapping the rules makes sense (to get the longest input match), but in my opinion this is not one of them because you may have several options, and I except your main interface predicate will look quite similar to `options([O|Os]) --> as_opt(O), " ", options(Os).`, where the deliminating blank should definitely not be part of the option that is being parsed (although you initially requested that).

Comment: Hey mat, I use the gprolog predicate `argument_list` to get the options, they appear as a list of atoms. Then I just iterate the list using the DCG start rule to set my data. Working well now. Thanks everybody who answered.

Answer (score 3):

There's a better solution than the one described by mat that is faster and avoids spurious choice points but it requires support for the `call//1` built-in non-terminal as found on e.g. SWI-Prolog, GNU Prolog, and other Prolog compilers. Also on Logtalk. Consider:

```
as_opt(Option) --> "--as=", list(Option).

list([L|Ls]) --> [L], list(Ls).
list([]) --> [].

as_opt2(Option) --> "--as=", call(rest(Option)).

rest(Rest, Rest, _).
```

Using SWI-Prolog to better illustrate the differences:

```
?- phrase(as_opt(Option), "--as=json").
Option = [106, 115, 111, 110] ;
false.

?- phrase(as_opt2(Option), "--as=json").
Option = [106, 115, 111, 110].

?- time(phrase(as_opt(Option), "--as=json")).
% 9 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (57% CPU, 562500 Lips)
Option = [106, 115, 111, 110] ;
% 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (63% CPU, 133333 Lips)
false.

?- time(phrase(as_opt2(Option), "--as=json")).
% 6 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (51% CPU, 285714 Lips)
Option = [106, 115, 111, 110].
```

The spurious choice-point comes from the definition of the `list//1` non-terminal. The performance difference is that, while `call//1` allows us to simply access the implicit list argument, the `list//1` non-terminal is doing a list copy element by element of that implicit argument. As a consequence, the `list//1` version performance is linear on the characters following the `--as=` prefix while the `call//1` performance is constant, independent of the number of characters after the prefix:

```
?- time(phrase(as_opt(Option), "--as=jsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjson")).
% 54 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (83% CPU, 2700000 Lips)
Option = [106, 115, 111, 110, 106, 115, 111, 110, 106|...] ;
% 4 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (69% CPU, 137931 Lips)
false.

?- time(phrase(as_opt2(Option), "--as=jsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjsonjson")).
% 6 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (79% CPU, 333333 Lips)
Option = [106, 115, 111, 110, 106, 115, 111, 110, 106|...].
```

Comment: Whooooosh! Paulo, that feels like a very good answer but it is straight over my head in terms of understanding! I have only been using Prolog for a month or three. I can see what you mean aobut choice points though, that's a good point indeed and one that I still need to get my head fully around. The reality is that my DCG will execute once to parse probably no more than four  or five command line arguments; it just has to work. Thanks though. :)

Comment: The `call//1` non-terminal call is translated to a `call/3` built-in predicate call where the first argument (the `rest(Rest)` closure) is shared and the two additional arguments (in the `call/3` call) are the two implicit arguments of the DCG rule. The definition of the `rest/3` predicate simply unifies the closure argument with the first (aka "input") implicit argument. There's also an alternative solution using the `call//1` built-in non-terminal with a lambda expression as argument that doesn't require an auxiliary predicate (such as `rest/3`) but it's a nasty trick and I will not post it.

Comment: Paulo, we should never mneet in real life. If your brain and my anti-brain collaborated the explosion could be deadly... thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use global variables. Instead, add argument(s) to DCG clauses, to get back the values:

```
anything([C|Cs]) --> [C], anything(Cs).
anything([]) --> [].
```

otherwise, the remainder is available as last argument of phrase/3, after rules succeded, 'consuming' the heading match.

Comment: I am relatively new to Prolog. I should read the manual for phrase/3 I guess as I am calling the start rule "by hand" in an iterative loop over the command line arguments.
I used global variables because I am writing a largish application with gprolog. Parsing the command line options is just one of the things I needed to do. It makes other bits of the code easy and my globals are strictly read only once they are set in the command line module. I fully understand your reservations though.