# When I should use <-- in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I read a lot examples with this estructure, think... is an assignation way... but i'm not sure and I dont know how is work.

```
fun0:- fun1([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],_).

fun1 <--
 [B],B>0,[A,B,C],
 fun2(A+B+C,something,Z),
 ...
```

PD: thanks for the help. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SWI -as far as I know- the only operators resembling what you are asking are:

> op 1200   xfx -->, :-
>
> op 1050   xfy ->

Are you sure you don't mean any of these?

I'm guessing you're talking about the --> DCG operator.
A DCG is defined by DCG rules of the form:

> head --> body.

Analogous to normal Prolog rules with:

> head :- body.

You could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902867/very-basic-dcg-prolog-syntax) question and [this](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse29) tutorial to understand some of the basics.

Good luck!